# how to apply global variables in Python and ROS?

Tags: python, opencv, global-variables, ros

I'm using ROS noetic to utilize multiple sensors

This is my code for read webcam images.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

rospy.init_node('read_images', anonymous=True)

bridge = CvBridge()

def image_callback(img_msg):
    global cv_image
    cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(img_msg, "bgr8")

def detect():
    global cv_image
    img = cv_image.copy()
    # long code for object detection 
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("Gray", img) # this is just simple test code for that
    cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub_image = rospy.Subscriber('image', Image, image_callback)
    global cv_image
    detect()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        rospy.spin()
```

However, I got this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jm-kim/catkin_ws/src/camera/src/scripts/read_imgs.py", line 36, in <module> 
    detect()
File "/home/jm-kim/catkin_ws/src/camera/src/scripts/read_imgs.py", line 24, in detect
    img = cv_image.copy()
NameError: name 'cv_image' is not defined
```

I think my global variable 'cv_image' was not applied well.

How can I apply the variable?